# How to change 0.0.0.0:8090 address to mastery.local in docker

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I have a container called web, it contains my application and apache webserver. When I put to browser address 0.0.0.0:8090 i get my working application. But i need to change this address to mastery.local. How do I do that without using /etc/hosts file.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 isn't an IPv4 address you can connect to.  How did you start the container?  Ports you publish with a `docker run -p` option are reachable via the host's DNS name (or IP address) and published port.

Answer (score 1):

This can only be achieved via DNS resolution.

The simplest way would be to add this entry to the `/etc/hosts`.

As an alternative you could setup an dedicated DNS server on your machine which resolves this address to `0.0.0.0` and then configure your machine to use this DNS server.

Comment: Could you please describe in detail the option with DNS.

Comment: you can look into bind but this is IMHO an overkill for such a simple usecase. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: But is there a way to do my task with docker network?

Comment: not if you want to call `mastery.local` from your host system. If you want to connect from another container to this one via a docker network you just have to set the container name of this one to `mastery.local`